# Upload Image to folder mvc 5 Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, upload, scaffolding

I´ve been struggling a long time with the last step, upload the image to a folder. I´ve made it without saving path to database. I want it all toghether now and right now image info and image path are saved  to db but the image itself will not appear in IMage folder. I´m jumping between Index and Create View. Thanks in advance for all kind of help and sorry for my English. /

Create.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
    </p>
    <p>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Imagefiles", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BildInfo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BildInfo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            <label for="file">Upload Image:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" />
        }
    </p>
```

}

INDEX.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Upload.Models.Imagefiles>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.file)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BildInfo)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.file)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BildInfo)
        </td>
        <td><img src="~/Images/@item.file" width="100" height="100" /></td>


        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.FilID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.FilID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.FilID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

IMAGEFILESCONTROLLER.CS

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "FilID,file,BildInfo")] Imagefiles imagefiles, HttpPostedFileBase imagesfiles)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Imagefiles.Add(imagefiles);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Files/"), imagesfiles.FileName);

            var data = new byte[imagesfiles.ContentLength];
            imagesfiles.InputStream.Read(data, 0, imagesfiles.ContentLength);

            using (var sw = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                sw.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Imagefiles.Add(imagefiles);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

I think **return RedirectToAction("Index");** in the above code exits the execution before it reaches the file persistence logic.

Move your file persistence logic before the line  **return RedirectToAction("Index");** in the if block.

You final code becomes something like this.

```
 [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "FilID,file,BildInfo")] Imagefiles imagefiles, HttpPostedFileBase imagesfiles)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Imagefiles.Add(imagefiles);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Files/"), imagesfiles.FileName);

                    var data = new byte[imagesfiles.ContentLength];
                    imagesfiles.InputStream.Read(data, 0, imagesfiles.ContentLength);

                    using (var sw = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                       sw.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                     }

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                  //Message to the user
                }
           }
```

Comment: I´m sorry to say it, but everything works fine, EXCEPT that the files don´t getting saved into the FILES folder..:( grateful for all kind of help..

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code if you still cannot save after applying MrGenius resolution "before the line return RedirectToAction("Index")".

Use imagesFile.SaveAs(path) instead of using FileStream (.SaveAs is more appropriate for file save to disk). Code imagesFile.SaveAs(path) will save the physical file to the path specified directly from the HttpPostedFileBase and you anyways save the path to Database.Your FileStream class sw.Write function may be the culprit here. I tried writing file using sw.Write and nothing got saved. FileStream may be used for saving images files to [databases](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/154626/FILESTREAM-MVC-Download-and-upload-images-from-SQL).

```
//Direct file save to the path
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(imagesfiles.FileName);
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Files/"), fileName);
imagesfiles.SaveAs(path);
```